# no sense/need/point

Tags: word-choice

> As the first space flights lasted just a few minutes, there was no **sense** to carry food onboard.
>
> As the first space flights lasted just a few minutes, there was no **need** to carry food onboard.
>
> As the first space flights lasted just a few minutes, there was no **point** to carry food onboard.

Which one is correct and why? For my eyes and ears all are ok, but only one is supposed to be right.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To my ears, **no need** and **no point** will both do, but they have different syntax:

> no need to carry food on board.

but

> no point in carrying food on board.

**No sense** is slightly different. It has the same syntax as ''no point'', but it implies that the action is foolish, rather than just unnecessary.

Comment: *No sense* has slightly different syntax: at least in my dialect, it's *no sense carrying*, without *in*.

Comment: For me the _in_ is optional with both _point_ and _sense_.

Answer (score 5):

All three are fine, but mean somewhat different things, depending on what you want to say.  If you intend something like:

> The flights were so short that no one expected the astronauts would become hungry and *have* to eat

then "need" is correct, or synonyms such as *require, necessitate, call for*, or (one definition of) *demand*.

If instead you want to say:

> The flights were so short that it would have been *useless* to bring food (since the astronauts did not have time to eat)

then "point" works, or synonyms such as *reason*.

Lastly if you want to say:

> The flights were so short that it would have been *unreasonable* (i.e. *nonsensical*) to bring food (for whatever reason, such as the extra weight would have affected the ship's trajectory)

then "sense" works, or related synonyms such as *value, logic, use* or *advantage*.

Note that both "sense" and "point" are words that sounds better (at least to me) paired with the gerund rather than the infinitive:

> As the first space flights lasted just a few minutes, there was no sense/point **carrying** food onboard.